# Getting at variables from CMS block insertions

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, php-5.4, variables

Magento 1.9

I am trying to add a form several times onto a CMS page with code similar to:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/html/jobappform.phtml"}}
```

But I want to pass a variable thru to the PHP in `jobappform.phtml` so I can differentiate between the different forms.

I have tried using:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/html/jobappform.phtml?a=1&b=2"}}
```

In the hope I get get at the variables with `$_GET`, but if I use this the form doesn't appear.

Is there a way of doing this:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/html/jobappform.phtml" a="1" b="2"}}
```

And then in `jobappform.phtml` can I get at variables `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can definitely use the code you pasted:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/html/jobappform.phtml" a="1" b="2"}}
```

And then in your template you can do:

```
$this->getA(); 
$this->getB();
```